# render animation is lagging in the output(i render as a PNG)

Tags: animation

i am creating videos in blender general and when i render animation it,the video has a lagi FPS like 1 or 2 secconds go after that it get freeze and it reapet again and again until video ends.what should i do?am i using a bad version of blender?

Comment: Where does the video lag? Are you playing your rendered frames in a video editing application? How many frames? What file format? What resolution?

Comment: You give too little informations as mentioned above. A screenshot of your output settings (with encoding settings if indeed a video) would help. I doubt this has anything to do with Blender, but rather an misuse of output formats/codecs or just weak hardware.

Comment: We need more information .. do you mean you render as a .PNG image-sequence, and then there is lag on playback? Where is there lag on playback? The Video Sequence Editor?